# MVC - Pass value to controller via JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a drop down

```
 <%=Html.DropDownList("genre", Model.genres, "", new { @onchange = ChangeMovie()" })%>
```

The JavaScript looks like (incomplete)

```
function ChangeMovie() {
    var genreSelection = container.find( '#genre' ).val();

    $.ajax({  
        "url" : "/Movies/GetGenre" ,
        "type" : "get" ,
        "dataType" : "json" ,
        "data" : { "selectedValue" : $( "#genre").val() },
        "success" : function (data) {}
    });
};
```

Conrtroller code

```
public ActionResult GetGenre(string genreName)
{
   //Need to get the `genreName` from the JavaScript function above.. which is
   // in turn coming from the selected value of the drop down in the beginning.

}
```

I want to pass the selected value of the drop down to the action result in the controller code via the js function. I need help manipulating the JavaScript code and the AJAX call code so the correct value is passed onto the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary quotes as well not returning JSON in your action

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Movies/GetGenre/",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {genreName: $("#genre").val() },             
    success: function (result) {
        if(result.Success) {
            alert(result.Genre);
        }
    }
});
```

Plus your controller isn't returning Json, modify your action to this

```
public JsonResult GetGenre(string genreName) {
    // do what you need to with genreName here 
    return Json(new { Success = true, Genre = genreName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I just need to pass genre.. not the city. I edited the OP. Thank you

Comment: It's a dynamically created property, JSON lets you create properties on the fly. By adding Success = true, I just created a boolean property and set it to true on the fly. If you had an error you could set it to false and include a Message = whatever your error was. By adding Genre = genreName I'm just creating a property on the fly and giving back the value that was sent in. You can change it to whatever you want

Comment: No problem, glad that got it going for you!

Answer (score 3):

The parameter name of the value you're posting in the Ajax request does not match the Action parameter name. **selectedValue** should be **genreName**.

Change this:

```
"data" : { "selectedValue" : $( "#genre").val() },
```

to this:

```
data : { genreName : $("#genre").val() },
```

Answer (score 3):

For model binding to function correctly, field names of passed json object should match parameter names of your controller action. So, this should work

```
"data" : { "genreName" : $( "#genre").val() },
```